# How to replace a part of email address using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a part of email address using regex. How to do it ?

For example : An email address `test.email+alex@gmail.com` is there and I want to replace the part of that email address from `+` to before `@` with '' so that final string will be `test.email@gmail.com`.

I tried with this given below :

```
str.replaceAll("[^+[a-z]]","");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with that:

```
\+[^@]*
```

Explanation:

1. `\+` matches + where \ is the escape character
2. `[^@]*` matches anything until it reaches @, where * means zero or more

The code is given below:

```
final String string = "test.email+alex@gmail.com";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+[^@]*");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);    
final String result = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

**[Regex Test Case](https://regex101.com/r/aHOI4r/2/)**

Comment: Hey, If i also want to remove '.' (dot) before '@' then how to write?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match either a dot or a plus sign till an @, you could use a positive lookahead to assert an `@` on the right for both cases and list each option using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
(?:\.|\+[^@]*)(?=.*@)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.` Match a dot
  - `|` Or
  - `\+[^@]*` Match `+` and 0+ times any char except a dot
- `)` Close group
- `(?=.*@)` Positive lookahead, assert an `@` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlIJzj/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/2dpffH)

In Java

```
str.replaceAll("(?:\\.|\\+[^@]*)(?=.*@)","")
```